# Want to store two variables permanently for an App in mobile OS

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to develop an App in Titanium Appcelerator all I need in that app is that it should always run in the background and collect current `GPS` coordinates and send it to a server. All I want the App to permanently remember is `IP` and `PORT` Number of the server. If the mobile is switched off and then on again IP and Port should be there. I think For this two variables only I should not use a Database. Is their any Other way to store `IP` and `Port` Number permanently other than using a database ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences for storing them.

Answer (score 10):

You can Try :-

// Set one time. this is work just like Database

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setString("ip",<value>);
```

// Get any where

```
Titanium.App.Properties.getString("ip","value");
```